# Need help for jQuery portfolio script

Tags: jquery

I am creating a portfolio page for my site. I want to display my works on my site, so I have this idea in my mind.

I will display all my works as images say 10 images. If anyone click on the particular thumbnail image, all the thumbnails will be faded out and the details about the work or project will be displayed on the page. Now they can click on "close" so that the current work will disappear and all the thumbnails will reappear.

I have achieved this using the following:

**HTML Code looks like this**

```
<div class="container project_container">
    <div class="four columns project proj1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/220x220" /></li>
    </div><!-- End three columns -->

    <div class="four columns project proj2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/220x220" /></li>
    </div><!-- End three columns -->

    <div class="four columns project proj3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/220x220" /></li>
    </div><!-- End three columns -->

    <div class="four columns project proj4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/220x220" /></li>
    </div><!-- End three columns -->
</div><!-- End Container -->

<!-- Project 1 to be displayed when all thumbnails are hidden -->
<div id="project1" class="container project_description">
    <div class="eight columns project_image">
        <p>This is an eight column text for image</p>
    </div><!-- End Eight Columns -->

    <div class="eight columns project_details">
        <p>This is an eight column text</p>
        <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
    </div><!-- End Eight Columns -->
</div><!-- End Container project description -->
```

**jQuery Code looks like this:**

```
$('.project_description').hide();

$('.proj1').click(function(){
   $('.project').fadeOut('fast', function(){
     $('#project1').fadeIn('fast');
   });
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('#project1').hide();
    $('.project').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

My question now is, suppose I have 20 projects to put on my site or what if I add them at later time? Do I need to keep adding the code in my custom.js file like this?

```
$('.proj2').click(function(){
   $('.project').fadeOut('fast', function(){
     $('#project2').fadeIn('fast');
   });
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('#project2').hide();
    $('.project').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

and so on changing proj2 to proj3,4,5,6..... and project2 to 3,4,5 etc.,?

Do I have any easy method to achieve this? I mean to ask without repeating the same code with minor changes do I have a way to achieve the above method?

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this - assuming that your structure is exactly like your example

```
$('.project_description').hide();

$('.project').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).index(); // get index of clicked project - assuming they are in the same order
   $('.project').fadeOut('fast', function(){      
     $('.project_description').eq(idx).fadeIn('fast'); // fadein only the clicked project
   });
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.project_description:visible').hide(); // hide all visible description
    $('.project').fadeIn('fast');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ePbaL/

Comment: Good one, I just always worry about depending explicitly on something like page position.

Comment: Very helpful hand on this. Thank you.

Comment: Slightly changed the html but again facing some problem. I have the code here http://jsfiddle.net/6vmbK/8/ Debug and ping me. Thanks!

Comment: @user23558 you just needed to stopPropagation().. So the event doesn't bubble up and trigger the other click event... http://jsfiddle.net/cUggY/

Comment: Oh nice :) There is lot for me to learn. Anyhow thanks for the code. Any suggestions on learning jQuery for beginners and intermediate?

Comment: best thing to do is to read through the api.. http://api.jquery.com/ then ask questions or lookup any questions you have on here as most of them have probably been answered before.

Answer (score 1):

Store the index of the project somewhere on the thumbnail. Either in data, or in the ID. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68UyY/5/)

```
<div class="four columns project proj1" data-projectindex="1">
```

Hide the descriptions with css, not js

```
.project_description {
    display: none;
}
```

Then make a single click handler which deals with any project.

```
$('.project').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).data('projectindex');
    $('.project').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $('#project' + index).fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

generalise the close button as well

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.project_description').hide();
    $('.project').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on() - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Then something like:

```
$(".project_container").on("click", "div", function(){
  console.log('i hit them all!');
});
```

(F12 in your browser to check the console btw)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a loop to bind the events to all your 'projects' :

```
for (i = 1; i <= projectsNum; i++) {

$('.proj' + i).click(function(){
   $('.project').fadeOut('fast', function(){
     $('#project' + i).fadeIn('fast');
   });
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    $('#project' + i).hide();
    $('.project').fadeIn('fast');
});

}
```

Answer (score -1):

no, make it dynamic.

For instance by using selector with LIKE:

instead of

$('#project1').fadeIn('fast');

put something like

$('div[id^="project"]').fadeIn('fast');

or

$("[id^=project]").fadeIn('fast');

should select all divs where id starts with "project"

you can do the same for class:

$("[class^=project]")